# WordPress: Widget checkbox option not storing the state

Tags: wordpress, checkbox

I am having trouble to keep the state of Wordpress Widget option checkbox. Here is my code

```
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('display_name'); ?>"><input
type="checkbox"
id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('display_name'); ?>"
name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('display_name'); ?>"
<?php checked(isset($display_name) ? $display_name : 0); ?> /> Display name</label>
```

Also I want to know how can I use multiple checkbox group to store and retrieve data

Answer (score 2):

Okay found the easy solution

Instead of `$display_name` in checked I simply changed to `1` and it works :)

Before:

```
<?php checked(isset($display_name) ? $display_name : 0); ?>
```

After:

```
<?php checked(isset($display_name) ? 1 : 0); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why but this answer did not work for me, after reviewing the [checked() documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/checked) I tried to follow some of those example with no luck. So eventually I resulted to this simple snippet (just plain php) and it worked as expected.

```
<?php echo $checked = ($display_name=== "on") ? "checked" : ""; ?>
```

Comment: Since I am using boolean value in database by 0 and 1 may be that could be the reason.